# Data insertion into delta table with changing schema

Tags: scala, pyspark, databricks

How to insert data into delta table with changing schema in Databricks.

In Databricks Scala, I'm exploding a Map column and loading it into a delta table. I have a predefined schema of the delta table.

Let's say the schema has 4 columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

So, one day 1 I'm loading my dataframe with 4 columns into the delta table using the below code.

```py
loadfinaldf.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true")\
       .mode("append").insertInto("table")
```

The columns in the dataframe change every day. For instance on day 2, two new columns `E`, `F` are added and there is no `C` column. Now I have 5 columns `A`, `B`, `D`, `E`, `F` in the dataframe. When I load this data into the delta table, columns `E` and `F` should be dynamically created in the table schema and the corresponding data should load into these two columns and column C should be populated as NULL. I was assuming that `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge","true")` will do the job. But I'm unable to achieve this.

My approach:
I was thinking to list the pre-defined delta schema and the dataframe schema and compare both before loading it into the delta table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use some Python logic?

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")
```

Then, push your dataframe into a dynamically created SQL table?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html